# Ruby On Rails Mongoid Group By

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, mongoid

For group by date I used `group_by` method.

```
Example: Product.all.group_by {|d| d.created_at } # return Hash
```

But kaminari not support Hash. I use Mongoid and me need group by date with page navigation (kaminari). How do it?

Comment: Have you referred to these related questions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482227/grouping-mongoid-objects-by-day?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354851/mongoid-group-conditions?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014009/mongoid-group-by-or-mongodb-group-by-in-rails?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569469/group-clause-mongoid-rails?rq=1

Comment: Wouldn't you call kaminari methods before the group_by?

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari only support paginate on array
for example

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(an_array).page(1).per(10)
```

group_by is not mongoid method, it Array's method, it is grouping all data in memory.
In order to use mongoid grouping feature, you need use mongodb map/reduce.

If you do need group result in memory, and show it in view, you need manually convert hash to Array

Comment: Did you know how to achieve that? I mean group_by and then paginate using kaminari?